# Issues with tomcat catalina_home

Tags: java, tomcat

The tomcat was working perfectly fine but then I renamed the folder it was in. The startup.bat refused to run after that. In cmd prompt it said wrong CATALINA_HOME path was there so I changed it to correct path but still it displayed the same thing.

I kept retrying this 5-6 times, renaming folder and even changing the entire directory but no success.

Comment: What version of Tomcat? When you run `catalina.bat start`, the script should tell you what the various paths are that it is using. Can you post those?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks for the response, sorry for late reply but I fixed the problem by doing a system restore (i am using windows 7)